# Constructing expression tree to call Any method on a IQueryable collection (nested query)

Tags: .net-core, lambda, reflection, ef-core-3.1

I'm trying to build a extension method to `IQueryable` that will check if there is any matching elements in a navigation property. What I do outside of the code below is to iterate over the properties of a type and check whether or not the property is a navigation property using `IModel`.

I'm having problems trying to figure out how to build the expression tree for the one-to-many relationships. What I want to achieve is something like `Entity.Collections.Any(Collection => Collection.Name == 'Filter')`, which would then be a where clause of the main query. The inner clause is built up outside of the sample below, but I believe the error occurs before reaching that expression.

I think that the delegate type of the `Lambda` is probably constructed wrong as it's not returning `bool`, it's returning `IEnumerable<Collection>`, but I can't figure out how it should be constructed if not like this.

I'm trying to follow [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/expression-trees/how-to-use-expression-trees-to-build-dynamic-queries) guide from the Microsoft docs.

The lines of code that is trying to solve what's mentioned above:

```cs
if (typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(targetType))
{
    var targetEntity = targetType.GetGenericArguments().First();
    var subArgument = Expression.Parameter(targetEntity, targetEntity.Name);

    var delegateType = typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(targetEntity, typeof(bool));
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda(delegateType, innerClause, Expression.Parameter(targetEntity));

    Expression.Call(
        typeof(Queryable),
        "Any",
        new Type[] { targetEntity },
        Expression.Property(argument, property.Name),
        lambda
    );
}
```

I get the below error at the line where I'm trying to create the `Expression.Call`.

`Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in System.Linq.Expressions.dll: 'No generic method 'Any' on type 'System.Linq.Queryable' is compatible with the supplied type arguments and arguments. No type arguments should be provided if the method is non-generic. '`

I've also tried to get the any method and invoking it:

```cs
var anyMethod = typeof(Queryable)
    .GetMethods()
    .Where(m => m.Name == "Any" && m.IsGenericMethodDefinition)
    .Where(m => m.GetParameters().ToList().Count == 2)
    .First();

var genericMethod = anyMethod.MakeGenericMethod(entityType);

genericMethod.Invoke(Expression.Property(argument, property.Name), new object[] { innerClause, subArgument });
```

And then I get this error instead:

`Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll: 'Object of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression3' cannot be converted to type 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[Collection]'.'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved it:

```cs
if (typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(targetType))
{
    var targetEntity = targetType.GetGenericArguments().First();
    var subArgument = Expression.Parameter(targetEntity, targetEntity.Name);

    var anyMethod = typeof(Enumerable)
        .GetMethods()
        .Where(m => m.Name == "Any" && m.IsGenericMethodDefinition)
        .Where(m => m.GetParameters().ToList().Count == 2)
        .First();

    anyMethod = GetAnyMethod().MakeGenericMethod(targetType);

    Expression.Call(anyMethod, Expression.MakeMemberAccess(argument, property), Expression.Lambda(x, subArgument));
}
```

So, the main problem was that I was trying to call the method on `Queryable` rather than `Enumerable`, which I should have since I was calling the method on a property rather than the queryable object.